# Trying to convert an asp.net login page in Asp.net mvc with react js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Iam very new to react js and i am trying to convert an asp.net login page in Asp.net mvc with react js.
Login.aspx

```
<div class="content">

                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                        </span>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Personal Number..."  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPswd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." runat ="server" TextMode ="Password"  ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblError"  runat ="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
<div class="footer text-center">
                                       <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btn_Login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btn_Login_Click"></asp:Button>
                                    <a href="Home.aspx" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                                </div>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1 objAd = new Service1();
        dynamic newResult = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            newResult = objAd.IsAuthenticatedWithMessage("mbs", txtUserName.Text.ToString(), txtPswd.Text.ToString());
            if (newResult.Equals("Authenticated"))
            {
                createSessionForUser(txtUserName.Text.ToString());
                lblError.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Invalid Username and Password..";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

How to convert this structure in react js and asp.net mvc  any idea would be appreciated.I had completed the setup for react js with  asp.net mvc in visual studio.

Comment: what have you tried so far? This is a bit too large for an SO question. Have you got a more specific problem?

Comment: @ADyson I have created all the setup .added reactjs through nuget package manager. but not getting idea how to create a form in reactjs and how can i pass  value from login.jsx on click of login button to controller.

Comment: where is your code then? ReactJS will probably have tutorials showing how to make forms using its syntax, or you can just make a form using regular HTML. If your form has a submit button, then when you click it, it will be submitted like any other HTML form. Just make sure the action attribute of the form points to the URL of an MVC action method which will process the data.

Comment: @ADyson i saw the example but it is bit confusing .if you can show me for this example which i mentioned (login.aspx) .then it will be helpful.

Comment: Well actually I'm not a React expert, my knowledge is in MVC. Maybe if you show us what you tried, and explain what exactly is confusing to you, then someone with the right expertise can help. Right now your description of the problem is too vague, and without code we can't see what you've done wrong or missed out.